# Badge Suggestion: Stumper

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties, unanswered-questions, badge-request

I propose a badge for offering a bounty on a question and having that bounty expire with no answers submitted with the question receiving some minimum number of upvotes.  Say, a minimum of 200 rep offered as the bounty, and say, 5 upvotes required after the bounty was offered.  In the case of the questioner and bountier being different, perhaps they should both get the badge?

Edit: in response to suggestions in the comments, I suggest the badge should only be awarded if there are no bounty-eligible answers submitted; i.e., no disqualification of the badge for junk answers; only valid upvoted answers should invalidate this badge.

Comment: What positive behavior are you trying to reinforce with this badge?

Comment: @Robert: It lets users worry less before placing a bounty on an obscure question. Also, it has consoling effects, like Tumbleweed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - offering significant bounties on questions that are hard to answer.

Comment: People will toss half-hearted answers at such questions in the hope of getting a couple of upvotes and winning the bounty; this will scuttle your shiny new badge (under your current rules).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: how is that different from the current situation with bounties?

Comment: @Paul: It isn't. But under the rules you've devised, a random answer will disqualify your badge.  Perhaps you should amend your rules to say "No bounty-qualified answers submitted."

Comment: I would also suggest that manually awarding the bounty to an answer would also negate earning the badge.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are trying to address here seems to be:

> It is not fair, I just spent 500 hundred rep on a bounty and got pretty much nothing back. Well at least I have this shiny "Stumper" badge

I would argue that you are addressing a problem with a solution that does nothing to fix the underlying issue. If we need to adjust our bounty mechanism to compensate for such cases, so be it. However a badge to compensate for "stumping" others seems the wrong approach. It is as if you are rewarding people for posting "unanswerable" questions. "Unanswerable" questions are **hugely** problematic cause the long tail hitting them from Google are left with a real bad taste when they show up in search results.

Comment: and if you look at it from a gaming point of view, it comes very close to 'buying' your badge with 500 rep.